# Best way to create the ground for house model

Tags: modeling

Im trying to create a 3d house model.

The tutorial I learnt from taught me how to create a plane for the ground of the house. The ground in the tutorial was a rectangle and so it can be easily achieved by creating the plane and specifying the X and Y.

I need a ground that is not usual rectangle, how should i go about doing it? Do i create a plane and make changes to the plane accordingly? or do i create multiple planes and join them to form the ground i need?

It will be great if steps are given as I am new to the Blender.

Thanks in Advance

UPDATE:
 [image: How I do it:]

Please comment if there is any other better way or if im doing it wrong in any steps.

Comment: Dunno if this is really a question for Stack Exchange. Since there are lots of required steps to turn a simple plane into a terrainmesh that fits to your house. You usually start with one plane. Tesselating the plane and do displacement is one possible way to go. Sculpting another. Then there are several shader techniques to make the terrain looking good. Plus some tricks like a wet map. You need some greens, sticks, stones etc. too. That's a job for the particle system. And so on. It's simply a pretty general question that can't be answered this generally.

Comment: thanks for the help. by not usual rectangle I mean by not the standard X by Y size of plane. but rather the ground can be made up by more than 1 plane. So im not sure if i should use 1 plane and start transforming into the shape i need or should i join lots of different size plane together to form the shape i need. forgive me if the question was too vague or sounded too stupid as im new to blender.

Comment: There is no stupid question. The whole matter is just too general. And so not easily to answer. Using more than one plane means to have seams. That's usually something that you want to avoid. However, when you for example want to have some far away mountains, then this can of course be another plane, as long as  the seams are not visible and disturbing. A square plane is also no must. It's just ways easier to work with square geometry for that purpose, since displacement uses usually a square image - In the end, allowed is everything that works. So toy around what works best for your case ;)